# How to get rid of UITextField padding?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, layout, flex3

Ignore padding didn't seem to do anything since no padding existed? I'm really confused here. I do NOT want the red areas. (Please ignore potato colors, I'm just debugging)

Debugging using flash firebug - the dark blue border with the plus in the top left represents the whole of the UITextField inside of my Label component. I was using [some other fixes](http://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/2009/10/scaling_label_text_size_to_fit.html) found from around the web regarding how to scale the text properly to fit the container and this is a breaking issue for those fixes.

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know how to achieve this? I just want to scale my text dynamically when the window is resized and the container resizes as a result.

edit: it's important to note that this label has a scale applied, I can tell that the padding is still there when it's smaller but it's much less noticeable without the scaling

Answer (score 1):

If I have problems like this I debug using FlexSpy.... to inspect the elements, and change properties in real time, very handy for things like this. Maybe that might be of some help...

https://code.google.com/p/fxspy/

Example of FlexSpy running

http://www.mieuxcoder.com/data/2007/12/FlexSpy-1.2/dashboard.html

Comment: Neat program, I'll definitely have to check this out.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I Know it isn't possible to get rid of the 2 pixel glutter around the text. For information about the padding arround the text see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextLineMetrics.html

You may use the .textWidth property to find out the with of your text. The exactly position of the text is dependent of the textfield.antiAliasType and the _textfield.gridFitType methods. With _textfield.gridFitType = flash.text.GridFitType.PIXEL The Flash player tries to render the text to pixels. This causing the 2 pixel glutter to vary between 1-3 pixels.

Comment: My screenshot is full-size so the glutter is way more than 2 pixels and is unacceptable for positioning text closer together.